# Why does it work in Safari but not in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

This HTML with simple CSS and JS works perfectly in Safari, but in Chrome (both Mac and Win) it does not work at all, does not even scroll... not sure the is JS, or the CSS or both.
I tried to change the script or the CSS but nothing works.

Please help

https://codepen.io/sinetempore/pen/oNwNKZr

Here is my HTML and my CSS:

```js
document.querySelector('.parallax').addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.p1, .p2').addClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('.p1, .p2').removeClass('hide');
  }
});

document.querySelector('.parallax').addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1200) {
    $('.p3').addClass('hide');
    $('.p2').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('.p3').removeClass('hide');
  }
});

document.querySelector('.parallax').addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1800) {
    $('.p3-text, .p3sottocntr, .p-main.p4-text').addClass('hidefoot');
  } else {
    $('.p3-text, .p3sottocntr, .p-main.p4-text').removeClass('hidefoot');
  }
});

/// Scroll back to top
$("a[href='.parallax']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  font-family: MuseoSans_700;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* ---------- LOGO ----------*/

.logo-p1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0px solid red;
  width: 120px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 22.5px);
  left: calc(50% - 60px);
  margin: 0;
}

.logo-p2 {
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}

.logo-p3 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}


/* ---------- PARALLAX ----------*/

.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: static;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 2;
}

.speed-1 {
  transform: translateZ(-6px) scale(7);
}


/* ---------- SECTIONS ----------*/

.p1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 3;
  background: white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
}

.p1.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.p2 {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0vh;
  background: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.p2.hide {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
  visibility: visible;
}

.p3 {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0vh;
  background: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.p3.hide {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
  visibility: visible;
}

.p-main.p4-text.hidefoot {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: black;
  /* position: relative; */
  left: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 250px;
}

.p-main.p4-text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 40%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 40%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  transition: all 0.9s;
  transform: translateY(250px);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.p4 {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
}

.p4.hidefoot {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
  visibility: visible;
}


/* ---------- TESTO SECTIONS ----------*/

.p-main {
  width: 355px;
  height: 230px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: flex-end;
  border: 0px solid red;
  filter: invert(0);
  font-family: MuseoSans-100;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.p3-text {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
  visibility: visible;
}

.p3-text.hidefoot {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.p-desc {
  line-height: 16px;
}

.p-desc b {
  font-family: MuseoSans_700;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.p-col {
  margin-top: 20px;
  column-count: 2;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-family: MuseoSans_700;
}


/* ---------- MENU SOTTO ----------*/

.sottocentro {
  width: 250px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: calc(0% - 0px);
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  filter: invert(0);
  font-family: MuseoSans-100;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  border: 0px solid red;
  right: 40px;
}

.p3sottocntr {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
  visibility: visible;
}

.p3sottocntr.hidefoot {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.sottocentro ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
  width: auto;
  border: 0px solid red;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  right: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.sottocentro ul li {
  border: none;
  text-align: right;
  width: auto;
}

.sottocentro ul li.begins {
  border: none;
  text-align: right;
  width: auto;
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/style.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parallax">
    <section class="p1 speed-1">
      <div class="logo-p1">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2021/doodle-champion-island-games-august-24-6753651837108999-s.png"></img>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <section class="p2">
    <div class="logo-p2">
      <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2021/doodle-champion-island-games-august-24-6753651837108999-s.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="p-main p2-text">
      <div>
        <p class="p-desc p2-desc"> <b>Lorem ipsum </b>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
          aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum..
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="p3">
    <div class="logo-p3">
      <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2021/doodle-champion-island-games-august-24-6753651837108999-s.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="p-main p3-text">
      <div>
        <p class="p-desc p3-desc"> <b>Sed ut perspiciatis </b>unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
          quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
          eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
          qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="p4">
    <div class="p-main p4-text">

    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note that `<img>` is unpair tag, so `</img>` is not valid (in HTML)

Comment: Anything in F12 console tab?

Comment: Got it.  </img> removed. Thanks.

Comment: F12 console all good, no errors, no issues.

Comment: A mystery, right? Not even on iOs works...